# AWS Textract table extraction broke rows with integers that has comma inside it into another column

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-textract

I would like to use AWS Textract to convert my image into tables in python and download it as CSV.

So, I followed the documentation and examples code from AWS here: 
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/textract/textract_python_table_parser.py

Apparently the code in the link above will separate the commas in the integers into another column. I will explain with image and steps to reproduce the error below:

So this is the example of my table in image form.
[image]

If you want to reproduce the error, clone the code in the github repo and type the following code in your cmd/terminal

```
python textract_python_table_parser.py <your-image-filename.png>
```

The error is as attached below:

[image]

As you can see in the ["Amount (USD)"] column, values with commas inside it will break into the ["Transaction Date"] column. Even I read the csv file in pandas also didn't work.

I wonder if which line of code in the GitHub repo broke the comma separation into another column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that in the [GitHub link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/python/example_code/textract/textract_python_table_parser.py), for line 114, just add "" to the curly bracket:

```
csv += '"{}"'.format(text) + ","
```

The reason is to transform all the texts into string so CSV won't take the commas inside the string into consideration during formating.

Comment: Nice this little change provided solution to my problem,
Thanks :)